Mapping drive in Azure
My client has a virtual machine deployed in Azure.
Now they want to map a drive from the virtual machine to their local machine.
I remotely helped them connect to the VPN, but when I attempted to map the drive, an error message appeared: "A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated."
I used the same method on my own computer, and the mapping worked fine. I’ve tried a few methods, such as .\username and ipaddress/username, but none of them worked.
I tried to these ways : .\username; server ip address/username; changed the account type into administrator; add the PIN login; add the new local credential; servername/username

Please check if 445 for SMB is open on the VM , are you able to ping the VM from your local machine? Map the drive manually using net use X: \<VM_IP_Address><shared_folder> /user:<VM_IP_Address><username> 
Look in Event Viewer for any specific errors related to authentication

Thanks for the reply. I successfully pinged the server's IP and can see the mapped drive, but I'm unable to access it. While there's no error message like 'A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated,' it keeps prompting me to enter my user account (Windows login email) and PIN repeatedly. I’m wondering if this could be an issue related to Azure Active Directory (AAD), especially since there’s no option to create a local user in the Windows settings.

You need to clarify the target disk that you are attempting to access, and how you are doing it. The target seems like it is on the local endpoint, and you are using a command or Windows Explorer to access the drive.
